# Android - WebView dies on resume

Tags: android, webview, nullpointerexception, onresume

1. I have Activity with some data displayed in WebView that I load with `WebView#loadDataWithBaseURL`
2. Then I have/click menu option that fires `android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND`
3. Choose email from the chooser
4. Google email comes up (as expected)
5. Discard email and hit back button
6. Action with WebView tries to `resume`
7. Bang - I get NullPonterException at line 4380 in WebView.java `if (mWebViewCore.getSettings().getNeedInitialFocus())` since mWebViewCore is now null

The only place in code where mWebViewCore is nullified is at WebView#destroy - how do I recover from this? Do I need to recreate the browser and load my data all over again, that seems pretty wasteful? I really appreciate good suggestion at this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I can tell you that I just tested using a `WebView` with `loadDataWithBaseURL()`, where the page I loaded had a link. Clicking on the link brings up the Browser application, as expected. BACK button-ing out of the Browser brings back my app with the `WebView` just fine, no exceptions.

So, either `ACTION_SEND`/Gmail are somehow special, or there is something more going on with your app.

Can you replicate the problem in a small project that you can post somewhere?

Comment: I also have a feeling that it happens with gmail only. I tried facebook and twitroid and it works fine, but coming back from gmail just kills me. I'll put this into standalone project and try

Comment: BTW - I did the scenario you described many times with no problem. This is specific to ACTION_SEND and GMail - I'm pretty sure about that

Comment: If true, that's pretty wild, and suggests a bug in Android somewhere. If you can come up with a reproducible scenario, post the symptoms and code over on http://b.android.com. JBQ is doing a yeoman's job of keeping tabs on new issues.

Comment: Nevermind... Entirely my fault. Actually - shining example of over-engineering where I was unnecessarily using service callbacks and had to monkey with situation where my partially build WebView would be abandoned (user clicks "Back" button) and I had to do WebView#destroy there which what was killing me in the scenario above. I'm back to simple handlers and it works fine